# Many to Many hibernate inverse side ignored

Tags: hibernate, jpa-2.0

Hi am reading the hibernate documentation.

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/annotations/3.5/reference/en/html/entity.html

> A many-to-many association is defined logically using the @ManyToMany
>   annotation. You also have to describe the association table and the
>   join conditions using the @JoinTable annotation. If the association is
>   bidirectional, one side has to be the owner and one side has to be the
>   inverse end (ie. it will be ignored when updating the relationship
>   values in the association table):

I understand everything but the last

> (ie. it will be ignored when updating the relationship values in the association table).

What does this mean? Example?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Suppose you have the following entities:

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @ManyToMany
    private Set<Course> courses;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Course {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "courses")
    private Set<Student> students;
    ...
}
```

The owner side is Student (because it doesn't have the `mappedBy` attribute). The inverse side is Course ((because it has the `mappedBy` attribute).

If you do the following:

```
Course course = session.get(Course.class, 3L);
Student student = session.get(Student.class, 4L);
student.getCourses().add(course);
```

Hibernate will add an entry for student 4 and course 3 in the join table because you updated the owner side of the association (`student.courses`).

Whereas if you do the following:

```
Course course = session.get(Course.class, 3L);
Student student = session.get(Student.class, 4L);
course.getStudents().add(student);
```

nothing will happen, because uou updated the inverse side of the association (`course.students`), but neglected to updated the owner side. Hibernate only considers the owner side.

Comment: Thank you! Very good explanation. So the only way is to update the owner? Both sides cant be owners right? How if I would like it to work both ways? Not possible?

Comment: Yes, you must update the owner side. Only one side can be the owner. There's no way to make it work both ways.

Comment: @JBNizet, and what do you say about the below answer??

Comment: I say that it's exactly what you shouldn't do.

Comment: @JBNizet, well could you explain more plz? why? what are the consequences?

Comment: The consequence is that instead of having one bidirectional association, you have 2 unrelated unidirectional both targeting the same join table, which is not a supported configuration. You can't expect Hibernate to do the right thing when updating these associations.

Comment: One co-worker is using a similar mapping as the below answer. I also dont like it but seems to work. The problem that i could guess to happen is that if both sides of relationship are associated and saved, there can be duplicate rows in intermediate table.. whats your opinion @JBNizet? Do you have a link or official reference where it says its not a recommended practice?

Answer (score 2):

To make it work both ways you need to have two separate relationships between your entities.
This can be represented by one join table in database but by default it will be represented by two so you have to explicitly say you want one join table.

I will demonstrate it using previously mentioned model of Student and Course.

```
@Entity
public class Student {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "student_course",
               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "courses_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "students_id")})
    private Set<Course> courses;
    ...
}

@Entity
public class Course {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "student_course",
               joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "students_id")},
               inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "courses_id")})
    private Set<Student> students;
    ...
}
```

In the above example we have 2 relationships with each side of Student<->Course relationship being owner of one relation.
So this solves the problem of saving changes to database only on the owner side since each side is owner of one relation.

But we have to keep in mind one fact that after saving data, relationship collections will NOT be reloaded from database
so programmer need to handle relationship collections by himself. By saying this I want to say that the easiest way is to
modify setters for relationship collections to rebuild cycle between entities like this:

```
public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    for(Course c : courses) {
        if (!c.getStudents().contains(this)) {
            c.getStudents().add(this);
        }
    }
    this.courses = courses;
}

public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
    for(Student s : students) {
        if (!s.getCourses().contains(this)){
            s.getCourses().add(this);
        }
    }
    this.students = students;
}
```