# Hibernate many-to-many relationship

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many

I have two mapped types, related many-to-many.

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "students")
public class Student{

...

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinTable(
    name = "students2courses",
    joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(
        name = "student_id",
        referencedColumnName = "_id") },
    inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(
        name = "course_id",
        referencedColumnName = "_id") })

public Set<Course> getCourses() {
    return courses;
}

public void setCourses(Set<Course> courses) {
    this.courses = courses;
}

...
}
```

__

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "courses")
public class Course{

...

@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, mappedBy = "courses")

public Set<Student> getStudents() {
    return students;
}

public void setStudents(Set<Student> students) {
    this.students = students;
}

...
}
```

But if I update/delete Course entity, records are not created/deleted in table students2courses. (with Student entity updating/deleting goes as expected)

I wrote abstract class HibObject

```
public abstract class HibObject {
    public String getRemoveMTMQuery() {
        return null;
    }
}
```

which is inherited by Student and Course.

In DAO I added this code (for delete() method):

```
String query = obj.getRemoveMTMQuery();
if (query != null) {
    session.createSQLQuery(query).executeUpdate();
}
```

and I ovrerided method getRemoveMTMQuery() for Course

```
@Override
@Transient
public String getRemoveMTMQuery() {
    return "delete from students2courses where course_id = " + id + ";";
}
```

Now it works but I think it's a bad code.

Is there a best way to solve this problem?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Many to Many hibernate inverse side ignored](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12552714/many-to-many-hibernate-inverse-side-ignored)

Comment: Thanks a lot. But it is not exactly the same. I read and understood why it doesn't work. But also I want to know, how to realize it apart of Hibernate. My solution works good, but I think that it's common problem, and there are should be better solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "apart of Hibernate"? If you always maintain both sides of the associations (and especially the owner side, of course), everything will run as expected.

Comment: JB Nizet, in your link I read "Only one side can be the owner. There's no way to make it work both ways.". So I mean that from other side I must delete records from relationship table(students2courses) "manually" (for example by pure SQL query)

Comment: And I want to know if there are any standard ways to solve this problem.

Comment: No, you simply need to also update the owner side of the association. Each time you remove a student from a course, make sure to also remove the course from the student. Same when adding a student to a course: also add the course to the student. In general, your entity graph should be consistent.

Comment: @JB Nizet   Thanks for the answer. I understood that I must consist both sides of relationship. So for deleting Course (which is NOT owner) should I write something like this: `for (Student stud : course1.getStudents()) {
   stud.getCourses().remove(course1);
   dao.update(stud);
  }
  dao.delete(course1);`